# Fill Color if range contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply formatting in VBA.

Range 3:3 on Sheet "Sheet2" to be highlighted RBG (221, 235, 247) if cells contain "holiday" "vacation" "sick" or "birthday".

I've written code different ways, but the only thing I could get sort of working was this:

```vb
With Range("3:3").FormatConditions.Add(xlTextString, TextOperator:=xlContains, String:="holiday")
    .Bold = True
End With
```

This seemed to bold the cells with "holiday" inside, but I couldnt find the code for Fill Color (tried: `With .Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)`). I also need multiple text string as stated above AND it needs to NOT use active sheet but a named sheet.

I could do this with conditional formatting, but I don't want to have to apply it to every new workbook on top of other formatting needed when I can hit the macro button once and be done with it.

Comment: Try recording a macro while adding the CF - that should give you the syntax you need.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried and unfortunately, I believe it gave me an End With Error, but I will try again and post what happens, thanks for the suggestion Tim!

Comment: Seems to work perfectly now I must have had a formatting error. Thanks for the suggestion, Tim.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Const FRM As String = "=NOT(AND(ISERROR(FIND(""holiday"",<addr>)),ISERROR(" & _
    "FIND(""vacation"",<addr>)),ISERROR(FIND(""sick"",<addr>)),ISERROR(FIND(""birthday"",<addr>))))"
    Dim rng As Range, addr As String
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows(3)             'or some other sheet...
    addr = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False) 'address of first cell
    
    With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                                  Formula1:=Replace(FRM, "<addr>", addr))
        .SetFirstPriority
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
     
End Sub
```

Or you can use a simpler formula by following this: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3793-excel-conditional-formatting-search-for-multiple-words.html

Answer (score 0):

[Excel Tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hge1k.png)

```
Sub colorMePlease()

'Give a nickname to your sheet:
Dim x As Worksheet
Set x = Sheets("Sheet2")

'Set a variable with the key works you want to find
Dim keyWords As String
keyWords = "holiday-vacation-sick-birthday"

'Just a counter
Dim c As Long

'For loop from row 3 (where your column starts to finding the last row of your column)
For c = 3 To x.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    'Check if the cell content (in lower case) is in your keyWords variable
    'The InStr function starts looking at position 1 and if if finds the
    'string you're looking, it returns a value larger than 0
    If InStr(1, keyWords, LCase(x.Cells(c, 3).Value))  0 Then
        x.Cells(c, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```